# How to prove that $\sum\limits_{k= 0}^n \frac{ku_k}{n^2}$ converges towards zero if $u_n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

I would like to prove that the following sequence converges to zero, given that $U_n$ converges to zero

$$v_n = \sum_{k= 1}^n \frac{kU_k}{n^2}$$

I have tried to use the epsilon definition and I got here :

$$- \epsilon \sum k <\sum_{k= N}^n \frac{kU_k}{n^2}< \epsilon \sum k $$

However I don't know what to do next, since this only work for $k \ge N $ where $N$ is the range that I got from the convergence epsilon definition for $u_n$

I there a better way using some theorem to prove this ? I was thinking about cesaro theorem  .

Comment: I can't understand how this would work ? could you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: This is a trivial consequence of the [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). Let $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}kU_k$ and $b_n = n^{2}$. Then, $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} = \frac{(n+1)U_{n+1}}{2n+1} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the definition of limit, given an $\epsilon\gt0$, there is an $N$ so that
$$
n\gt N\implies|u_n|\lt\epsilon\tag1
$$
Furthermore, find
$$
M=\max_{n\le N}|u_n|\tag2
$$
Then, for $n\gt N$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{ku_k}{n^2}\,\right|
&\le\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{ku_k}{n^2}\,\right|+\left|\,\sum_{k=N+1}^n\frac{ku_k}{n^2}\,\right|\\
&\le\underbrace{M\frac{N^2+N}{2n^2}}_{\to0}+\underbrace{\epsilon\frac{n^2+n}{2n^2}}_{\to\frac\epsilon2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{ku_k}{n^2}\,\right|\le\frac\epsilon2\tag4
$$
Since this is true for all $\epsilon\gt0$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{ku_k}{n^2}\,\right|=0\tag5
$$

Comment: $\frac {n^2+n}{2n^2} $ is greater than $\frac {1}{2} $, but otherwise, this seems fine. Just replace $\frac {\epsilon}{2} $ with $\epsilon $.

Comment: The limit is $\frac12$, so we don't need to replace $\frac\epsilon2$.

Comment: So $M$ in (2) is the greatest term $u_n$ for which $n<=N$ ?

Comment: This is the maximum of $|u_n|$ for *all* $n\le N$.

Comment: Thank you so much, could you please explain a bit more  to me where did you get the right term of the inequality in 3 ?

Comment: Since $|u_k|\le\epsilon$ and $\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}\le\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2n^2}$, we have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{ku_k}{n^2}\le\epsilon\frac{n^2+n}{2n^2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, how does someone like me (first year in real analysis and in college) reach to such proofs ? I mean I've been trying for more than a week without any result  . any tips ?

Comment: Takes experience. Also, this is a standard bad-part/good-part proof where the first part of the sum can behave badly but since it is bounded will go to zero, and the last part behaves well and so will also go to zero.